# Where's the best practice location for non-table-related classes in Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Where do most Rails apps usually keep their non-active-record classes?

In app/models?
In lib/some_file.rb?

Someplace else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what is the purpose of this class. If this is something like a model. On example, by default mailers are put in `app/models` and it isn't ActiveRecord. If you want to add some classes that are used in your application in many places and it isn't model-related, then probably the best place is to put it in a `lib` directory. If you want to reuse it, you can also create a plugin with your class and then it would be placed in `vendor/plugins`.

You can also put it in `config/initializers` if it fits into this category.

To sum up: it depends what your class is about. Put it in a place where it fits. If you have doubts, put it in `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your files in app/models, they'll be reloaded along with all other models. This eases development. In app/models, I have:

```
acts_as_bookable.rb
subclass_responsibility_error.rb
user.rb
```

To Rails, app/models is just a location from which it reloads.